# Nuxt loading progress bar loads multiple times

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm using default nuxt loading bar, it works well on simple pages. But when I use multiple axios requests progress bar loads every time request is sent. I want progress bar to understand all those request as a single page load. I used Promise.all and it kind of worked. But my problem is that I am using asynchronous vuex dispatch methods.

So my code is something like this, with three different asynchronous dispatch and progress bar loads three times. How can I make it so, that it loaded only once. Thanks

```
async fetch({  store }) {
    await store.dispatch('LOAD_DATA_1')
    await store.dispatch('LOAD_DATA_2')
    await store.dispatch('LOAD_DATA_3')
}
```

Comment: did u try with a `promise.all` ?

Comment: It worked on simple axios get methods, but I couldn't figure out how to use promise.all on dispatch methods. Have you any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's loading three separate times because your requests are taking place sequentially, one after another, not all at once. To get around this, you can manually start/stop the loader.

First, you'll want to prevent the nuxt axios plugin from triggering the loading bar. See [here](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options#progress).

```
this.$axios.$get('URL', { progress: false })
```

Then, you can manually start and stop the loading bar programatically before/after the requests are completed.

```
this.$nuxt.$loading.start()
this.$nuxt.$loading.stop()
```

Full example:

```
async fetch({  store }) {
    this.$nuxt.$loading.start()
    await store.dispatch('LOAD_DATA_1')
    await store.dispatch('LOAD_DATA_2')
    await store.dispatch('LOAD_DATA_3')
    this.$nuxt.$loading.stop()
}
```

edit 1 (see comment):

To use in asyncData/fetch you can use the following. I'm not sure  you should be accessing the components like this, but I don't see another way to access the $loading module within the context...

```
async fetch(ctx) {
    // access the loading component via the access context
    ctx.app.components.NuxtLoading.methods.start()

    // example, wait 3 seconds before disabling loader
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000))

    ctx.app.components.NuxtLoading.methods.finish()
},
```

Comment: Thank you very much. progress: false worked. I created plugin and disabled progress variable globally via $axios.onRequest.
One more question. Do you any idea how to use this.$nuxt.$loading.start/finish inside fetch method. There is no this.$nuxt inside fetch and asyncData methods.

Comment: I've edited my response @ShotoAzikuri. I'm not sure that it's the best way to access the $loading module, but I also don't see another way to get to it from the app context. Let me know if that works and accept the answer if so :)

Comment: It works even without manually starting and finishing loader. I think it is because fetch  method runs after route change and route change automatically triggers loading.
Thanks you very much, for your help.